# Is it possible to create an app that "picks up" a particular wifi signal as a cue to turn on the app or blue tooth?

Tags: ios, mobile, bluetooth, wifi, wifi-direct

You know how when you go into your wifi signal page
you see a list of all the wifi your phone is currently picking up?
If a person were to download this special app where he or she consent to it
is it possible for this app to recognize one of the signals as a cue to turn on bluetooth or launch an app?

Comment: Even if it were possible to detect a wifi station, it's not possible to turn on bluetooth from an app or launch an app automatically.

Answer (score 0):

No this isn't possible without jailbreaking since it requires a private library (Apple80211). You can only get the SSID of the network your device is currently connected to.